# SSH Ethernet Forwarding Does Not Seem to be Working

Tags: ssh, vpn, ethernet, forwarding, tap

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on both the client and server. I have set `PermitTunnel yes` in `sshd_config` in both the client (I might not need it on the client) and the server. I have also set `Tunnel yes` and `TunnelDevice any:any` in the `ssh_config` in both the client and the server (I might not need it in the server), and ensured that the server is restarted after the configuration has been applied. I have setup a TAP device on both ends, named `tap0`, using the following command ran in both ends:

```
ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap
```

Then, on the `root` account in my client machine, I SSH'd into the `root` account of my server machine using the following command:

```
ssh -w 0:0 root@<my server> -p <ssh port>
```

However, I do not seem to be able to get any of the TAP adapters to be `UP` (i.e. it doesn't seem that SSH is using the TAP adapters in any of the ends). I have ran the following command in both ends, and found that the state of the TAP adapters are still `DOWN`:

```
ip link show tap0
```

output:

```
30: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:ff:d7:19:ee:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This means I cannot also ping any of the devices on any of the ends (I tried setting a static IP on both ends and no luck).

I have also tried the latest Fedora for the server side as well, and found the same output.

I am not sure what am I missing here, and would love some help.

P.S. The server is is server ISO VirtualBox VM, and I am SSHing into it using NAT port forwarding of the guest's `22` port to some host port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the `Tunnel` argument to `ethernet` not just `yes` to get layer 2 tunneling.

From the `ssh_config` man page.

> **Tunnel**
>
> Request tun(4) device forwarding between the client and the
> server.  The argument must be `yes`, `point-to-point` (layer 3),
> `ethernet` (layer 2), or `no` (the default).  Specifying yes requests
> the default tunnel mode, which is point-to-point

Comment: This seem to have worked: `ssh -o Tunnel=ethernet -o TunnelDevice=0:0 -w 0:0 -p <server port> root@<server host>`. Thank you very much. You are awesome!

Comment: I want to clarify part of the root cause I have discovered, though. It seems that `-o` arguments must exist before `-w` argument for it to work. Can you please add it as part of the answer to have a complete answer for everyone who stumbles upon the same problem? Your original answer is part of the full answer, but it is also missing the ordering of the commands.